# How to get the server to only reply back after getting a message from the client? (UDP Pinger, sockets)

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

I'm currently developing a UDP pinger, where the client should send a message (Ping) and receive pong back 10 times. However, the messages are sent 10 times at the same time, where the idea is to have the server send pong back after receiving ping, not having the terminal sending everything at once.

This is due to the for loop around the server.send, which i am aware of. I'm just not sure how i can get the server to only send a reply back after receiving a message, making the server record a different timing for each message. I hope my problem makes sense. I have so far come up with this:

```
var host = "127.0.0.1", port = 33333;

var dgram = require( "dgram" );
var buffer = require('buffer');
var server = dgram.createSocket( "udp4" );

var date1 = new Date()
var today = Buffer.from(date1)



server.on('listening', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log(`server listening on port ` + 4000 + ' and address 127.0.0.1');
  });



server.on( "message", function( msg, rinfo ) {
    for (let message = 0; message < 10; message++){
    const message = 'Ping'
    server.send( message, 0, msg.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.address, date1 );
    console.log( rinfo.address + ':' + rinfo.port + ' - ' + msg + ' . ' + date1 );
}});



server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
    server.close();
  });

server.on("close", function(){
  console.log("\n Client is offline")
})

server.bind( port, host );
```

Client side:

```
var host = "127.0.0.1", port = 33334;

var dgram = require( "dgram" );
var buffer = require('buffer');
var client = dgram.createSocket( "udp4" );

var date1 = new Date()
var today = Buffer.from(date1)
console.log(date1)


client.on('listening', () => {
    const address = client.address();
    console.log(`client listening on port ` + 4000 + ' and address 127.0.0.1');
  });


client.on( "message", function( msg, rinfo ) {
    console.log( rinfo.address + ':' + rinfo.port + ' - ' + msg + ' - ' + date1 );
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
    server.close();
  });

client.on("close", function(){
  console.log("\n Client is offline")
})

client.bind( port, host ); //client listens to a port

var message = "Pong!"
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 33333, "127.0.0.1", date1 );
```

So far the code also prints out the time when each message is sent (I get the same time for all of the messages sent). Any ideas as to how i could maybe incorporate the round trip time after the 10 pings and pongs have been sent would be amazing.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to ping 10 times and get one pong each time? From your wording it seems that you want 10 pongs for each ping

Comment: @Rojo I was a bit unsure of how to formulate my question, but yes you understood it correctly.

Comment: So you just want to cap the number of pings from each user at 10? Or does something special happen at 10 ping pongs?

Comment: @Rojo It should reach 10 pings from each user, where essentially the delay between the messages is counted with round trip time. In other words, the pings are computed. At the moment it just prints everything out at once, leaving no time difference between message

Comment: @Rojo I must also add that it should calculate the delays between the messages that were sent, at the end of the 10 ping pongs. But i haven't implemented that yet as i'm still unsure of how that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to count the number of times a ping is received and check if it equals ten:

```js
var numPingPongs = 0;

server.on( "message", function( msg, rinfo ) {
  if (numPingPongs < 10) {
    const message = 'Ping'
    server.send( message, 0, msg.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.address, date1 );
    console.log( rinfo.address + ':' + rinfo.port + ' - ' + msg + ' . ' + date1 );
    numPingPongs++;
  } else {
    // Reached ten ping pongs, do whatever here.
  }
});
```

I assumed that you'd want to calculate latency or whatever on the server side, so I just wrote this for the server. But you can apply the logic to the client as well.